How can I get the Section headers (title/displayName) from Sharepoint pages using Graph Api?
When I use the endpoint as shown below the information about Section headers seems to be missing.
YAML

GET /sites/{site-id}/pages/{page-id}/microsoft.graph.sitePage/webparts

For eg. These information can't be seen on the response.

If not by Graph API , is there any other way (SP API) ?

I found that at most I can only get the inner html of the webpart in the section. Regarding section, the official does not provide more attributes for this API for us to use.
As you mentioned, SharePoint REST API. It is also only works for simple pages that have plain text. Nor can get Section name.
And I noticed that some end users have also proposed the same request, it is highly recommended that you can vote this ticket. Many features of our current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback. With requirements like this increase, the problem may well be released in the future.


